# ¿Por que no me guarda la palabra en la lista?

Tags: c#

Quiero leer lo que hay en un richtexbox, quiero encontrar la palabra "if" en ese texto, si el valor inicial de i='i' y el valor inicial+1  para leer la siguiente letra del texto es igual a 'f' me va aguardar en la lista "if" pero al querer poner en un listbox los valores de la lista no me guarda nada

```
  public void BuscarPalabras(string texto)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < texto.Length; i++)
        {
            if (texto[i] == 'i' && texto[i++] == 'f')
            {
                Palabras.Add("if");
            }
        }
    }
```

Aquí paso la información de la lista al listbox pero no me aparece nada

```
 if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = objArchivoCodigo.LeerArchivos(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
        objArchivoCodigo.BuscarPalabras(richTextBox1.Text);
        listBox1.DataSource = objArchivoCodigo.Palabras;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

prueba a cambiar

```
//Aquí le estas diciendo que sume uno a i, no que busque en i + 1
if (texto[i] == 'i' && texto[i++] == 'f')
```

por

```
//aquí le dices que busque en la siguiente posición a i, i + 1
if (texto[i] == 'i' && texto[i + 1] == 'f')
```

Aunque parezca lo mismo, no lo es, en el primer caso incrementa la variable, después de pasar por ella, o sea, la tendría en cuenta para el siguiente bucle

Sin embargo, en el segundo caso, la variable la incrementas para la lectura

el código correcto sería:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine("Introduzca un texto");
        String texto;
        texto = Console.ReadLine();
        //convertimos el texto introduido por teclado en un array de tipo char
        char[] ar = texto.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ar[i] == 'i' && ar[i++] == 'f')
            {
                /como no tengo el arraylist creado, en lugar agregar el if simplemente lo imprimo para que veas que ésta parte ya funciona
                Console.WriteLine("if");
            }
        }
```

Pues con un string no puedes interactuar por posiciones en el texto, para ello deberías de crear un array, en éste caso yo lo he creado de char, con cada caracter del texto o palabra

Comment: Gracias si me sirvió